# Create multiple windows using one tkinter button in python

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am opening other windows from a single tkinter button as shown here:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-toplevel/
The code shown there is

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Toplevel Window')

        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Close',
                command=self.destroy).pack(expand=True)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.title('Main Window')

        # place a button on the root window
        ttk.Button(self,
                text='Open a window',
                command=self.open_window).pack(expand=True)

    def open_window(self):
        window = Window(self)
        window.grab_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

If I run this program, it is not possible to hit the "Open a window" button twice to get two Toplevel instances. I would like to get as many instances as I like to with only one button. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Remove the `window.grab_set()`. I think that it stops all events from reaching your main window

Comment: The tutorial probably added in the `grab_set()` to prevent multiple windows from opening. Its useful for things like login windows being opened. It has other uses as well. As @TheLizzard said just remove that line.

Comment: Thanks! How can I access one of the instances of the Window class after being created? For example, if I had a second button in App that should toggle a variable of the last-created instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
window.grab_set()
```

This is setting a *grab* on the first window that is created. That means that all events from both the keyboard and the mouse are funneled to the first window that is created. That means you can no longer click on the button in the root window until the grab has been removed. Note that if the window is destroyed, the grab is automatically removed.

Grabs are typically used when creating a modal dialog -- a dialog which requires user input before the program can continue. By doing a grab, you insure that the user can't interact with the main program until they've interacted with the dialog.

The solution is simple: remove the call to `window.grab_set()` if your goal is to be able to open multiple windows which can all be used at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `window.grab_set()`. The grab_set() method routes all events for this application to this widget. Whatever events generated like button-click or keypress is directed to another window.

```
def open_window(self):
    window = Window(self)
```

Comment: Isn't this what I said in the comments 7 min ago?

Comment: It doesn't bother me that this is basically the same thing that was commented when the commenter did not post an answer. What does bother me there is not explanation on what is going on here. Sujay can you add some documentation or explanation on why this is going on. It would improve the quality of your answer.